# Copy + paste MS Word doc into Libre office doc?

Tags: microsoft-word

On Ubuntu 14.04 I tried to copy an MS word docx.into a blank libre office document ( control C + Control V) but nothing happens. How can I do this?

Comment: I am confused, please clarify.  How do you have the .docx file open?  Isn't it open in LibreOffice already?  Or are you doing something different?  I just opened a docx in writer, ctrl-a to select all, ctrl-c to copy and then ctrl-v pasted into new writer file.  Are you selecting text or just doing ctrl-c?

Comment: why not just open the MS Word document in LibreOffice?

Comment: I have all my MS Word documents/folders on an external hard drive. When I open a Word .docx, it shows up as LibreOffice writer. When I copy the info control A, control C, and paste it (control V) into a untitled document on the ubuntu desktop (-/Desktop)-gedit), whatever that means, nothing gets pasted in. And when I open a LibreOffice writer doc, + paste, nothing goes in there either. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Open docx file in one window and blank in other then try if nothing try without shortcuts in *edit - copy* and *paste*

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing if you see my comment above. And even in the Internet, if I highlight a passage and want to copy it + paste it into a blank Libre Office, nothing happens.

Comment: I rejected your edit copying the comment into the answer; That would make it very unclear who actually meant what.

Comment: I could not edit out my  last incorrect comment. I can copy + paste from internet sites into LibreOffice writer + into a blank desktop document.

Comment: dont use shortcuts, i thinks its the point